# Present Continous Tense

Tags: tense, present-continuous

Please explain to me why we use the present continuous tense in the following sentences:

> 1. I want to lose weight, so this week I am not eating lunch.
> 2. I am getting tired.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to understand the correct use of Present Simple and Present Continuous.

**Present Simple** is used to express:

- That something happens in general (regularly, often, never, ...),
- A daily routine,
- That something is arranged for the near future.

**Present Continuous** is used to express:

- That something is happening right now,
- That something is only going on for a limited period of time,
- That something is going to happen in the near future.

So, in the first part of the ***first sentence***, we use Present Simple because somebody expresses that he wants to do something in general. In the second part of the sentence, we use Present Continuous because the person scheduled to do something in the near future.

While in the ***second sentence*** it's pretty straightforward because the person says that he is getting tired right now!

Comment: Present continuous is also used for a change happening over time, so "I am getting tired" could mean that.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence the present continuous tense is used to talk about arrangements for events at a time later than now.

In the second sentence You start to feel tired or you are feeling like tired or tiredness is slowing taking over you.